# Extracting information from HTML using XPath

Tags: html, xpath

I have a snippet of html which I extracted from the source of a webpage I'm working on:

```
<span itemprop="homeLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta itemprop="name" content="Kansas"/>
```

...and I'd like to extract the location, `Kansas` from it, using Xpath.

Using an [Xpath checker](http://ponderer.org/download/xpath/), I have been testing this but to no avail.

I tried

```
//*[@itemprop="homeLocation"]/meta[@itemprop="name"]/@content
```

and similar attempts, but can't seem to get a match. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you refer to `//span...` element instead of `//*...` ?

Comment: yes Mr. V, I gave that a shot too, no difference!

Comment: Please provide more context.  Also note that the fragment you provided isn't well-formed: `itemscope` has no value and the `span` isn't closed.

Comment: ok I will add more info...also, I agree, `itemscope` don't have the value, but I didn't write the code and there's nothing I can do to change it...

Comment: you will not able to use xPathes without having proper xml. You should use external libraries that allow to process invalid xmls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xPath is absolutely valid.
The problems are with xml.

1. Close `span` tag.
2. Set some value for `itemscope` attribute.

And the most important. xPath checker your are trying to use seems to have some bugs.  Check this one: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Xml I've used:

```
    <span 
      itemprop="homeLocation"
      itemscope=""
      itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
             <meta itemprop="name" content="Kansas"/>
  </span>
```

Result:

```
Attribute='content="Kansas"'
```